# Canvas drawImage() method - how to offset source image in a scaled and offset origin?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

#### PROBLEM

Source image dimensions:

- width: 2448
- height: 2448

Canvas dimensions:

- width: 323
- height: 323

Image position and scale on the canvas

- x: 141.8 (x coordinate where to place the image on the canvas)
- y: 214.55 (y coordinate where to place the image on the canvas)
- width: 178.7 (the width of the image to use (stretch or reduce the image)
- height: 134.1 (the height of the image to use (stretch or reduce the image)

I have called drawImage like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height)
ctx.drawImage(img, 141.8, 214.55, 178.7, 134.1);
```

yes! the image is scaled and positioned correctly on the canvas.

but oh no! it is cutting off the face of my subject! I need to offset the source image while maintaining the positioning and scaling I had on the canvas.

I know that I need to use

```
context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
// sx: x coordinate where to start clipping
// sy: y coordinate where to start clipping
// swidth: The width of the clipped image
// height: The height of the clipped image
```

I need to offset in the x direction by 158 of the original source image (2448 of width)

After hours and hours of trying different equations and reading the documentation to find the correct numbers to fill in the missing variables, I couldn't figure it out how to offset the source image without altering the positioning and scaling I already had.

I referred to documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

and tried to experiment here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage2

need the equations and explanation to calculate sx, sy, swidth, and sheight!

Comment: 214.55 + 134.1 = 348.65. your canvas height is 323